# How to reapper the sphere shape of SVG tag code by Raphael description exactly?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I'm trying to figure a Raphael.js shape(sphere) which is based on following SVG tag code.

I have succeed in basic similar sphere style by the description :

```
  Paper.circle(100, 100, 30).attr({ fill: "r(0.35, 0.25)#FFFFFF-#252525:96-#000000", stroke: "none"});
  // radius is 30
```

But I can't reappear exactly.  ---> [[picture]](http://www.dotup.org/uploda/www.dotup.org4642217.png)

```
** The tag code of sphere ... main part is extracted **
<g id="layer1">

 <radialGradient id="path5725_3_" cx="156.0352" cy="657.6802" r="200.0004" 
  gradientTransform="matrix(1.0404 0.7962 0.8145 -1.0643 -531.7884 745.2471)" 
  gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">

  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
 </radialGradient>

 <path id="path5725" fill="url(#path5725_3_)" d="M445.037,229.105c0,113.218-89.543,205-200,205c-110.457,
  0-200-91.782-200-205s89.543-205,200-205C355.494, 24.105,445.037,115.887,445.037,229.105z"/>

</g>
** ---------------------------------------- **
```

[Here](http://www.dotup.org/uploda/www.dotup.org4642228.png) the completed picture of tag code is linked.

How to describe(modify) the Raphael.js code to reappear the picture ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Radial gradients have two sets of attributes that control how the gradient is rendered.

- `cx` and `cy` set the centre of the gradient. (where the centre of the gradient circle is)
- `fx` and `fy` set the focus of the gradient (ie. where offset="0" is).

[image: The cx,cy and fx,fy attributes of a radial gradient]

To get the gradient you are after, you need to set `cx` and `cy`.  However Raphael's gradients use `fx` and `fy` instead.  When `cx` and `cy` are not specified, they default to the centre of the element.

Unfortunately, from what I can see, it doesn't look like you can over-ride that Raphael behaviour.

Comment: Thank you BigBadaboom.
I've checked Raphael's API again. It doesn't have color-matrix effect, so Raphael can't draw the gradation which I want to.
The best picture which I've achieved is :

  some_element.attr({fill: "r(0.35, 0.25)#fff-#000:95-#000", stroke: "none"});
*** It is important to insert #000:95 .